# WP_Query returns 0 Results on Safari ONLY

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I am trying to implement some custom logic into a website I'm building, which required that i create a custom post type which i query to display on a woocommerce product page.

I use the following function for the query.

```
function get_mod ( $post_name, $post_type = 'productmods' )
{
    $post_ids = new WP_Query(array
    (
    'name'  => sanitize_title($post_name),
    'post_type'   => $post_type
    ));
    return $post_ids;
}
```

This function works successfully for all browsers except for safari however. When I look at the page in safari, and I output a vardump onto the page of the query object. It returns different results depending on which browser I use. Below are screenshots:

- In Chrome
  [image: Chrome Browser]
- In Safari
  [image]

Has anyone ever heard of this happening? I've tried google searching it, but, I only get the issue non-specific to which browser its happening in. And all of the solutions I've tried do not work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

### EDIT

As per the comments. Here is the plaintext of the output given on both safari and chrome:

### IN SAFARI

```
WP_Query Object
(
[query] => Array
    (
        [name] => signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing
        [post_type] => productmods
    )

[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [name] => signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing
        [post_type] => productmods
        [error] => 
        [m] => 
        [p] => 0
        [post_parent] => 
        [subpost] => 
        [subpost_id] => 
        [attachment] => 
        [attachment_id] => 0
        [static] => 
        [pagename] => 
        [page_id] => 0
        [second] => 
        [minute] => 
        [hour] => 
        [day] => 0
        [monthnum] => 0
        [year] => 0
        [w] => 0
        [category_name] => 
        [tag] => 
        [cat] => 
        [tag_id] => 
        [author] => 
        [author_name] => 
        [feed] => 
        [tb] => 
        [paged] => 0
        [meta_key] => 
        [meta_value] => 
        [preview] => 
        [s] => 
        [sentence] => 
        [title] => 
        [fields] => 
        [menu_order] => 
        [embed] => 
        [category__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [category__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [category__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_name__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
        [suppress_filters] => 
        [cache_results] => 1
        [update_post_term_cache] => 1
        [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
        [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
        [posts_per_page] => 10
        [nopaging] => 
        [comments_per_page] => 50
        [no_found_rows] => 
        [order] => DESC
    )

[tax_query] => 
[meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
    (
        [queries] => Array
            (
            )

        [relation] => 
        [meta_table] => 
        [meta_id_column] => 
        [primary_table] => 
        [primary_id_column] => 
        [table_aliases:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [clauses:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [has_or_relation:protected] => 
    )

[date_query] => 
[request] => SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'productmods'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
[posts] => Array
    (
    )

[post_count] => 0
[current_post] => -1
[in_the_loop] => 
[comment_count] => 0
[current_comment] => -1
[found_posts] => 1
[max_num_pages] => 0
[max_num_comment_pages] => 0
[is_single] => 1
[is_preview] => 
[is_page] => 
[is_archive] => 
[is_date] => 
[is_year] => 
[is_month] => 
[is_day] => 
[is_time] => 
[is_author] => 
[is_category] => 
[is_tag] => 
[is_tax] => 
[is_search] => 
[is_feed] => 
[is_comment_feed] => 
[is_trackback] => 
[is_home] => 
[is_404] => 
[is_embed] => 
[is_paged] => 
[is_admin] => 
[is_attachment] => 
[is_singular] => 1
[is_robots] => 
[is_posts_page] => 
[is_post_type_archive] => 
[query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => 1f637d9a855417c5b7cd26de9027165b
[query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
[thumbnails_cached] => 
[stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
[compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => query_vars_hash
        [1] => query_vars_changed
    )

[compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => init_query_flags
        [1] => parse_tax_query
    )
 )
```

### IN CHROME

```
WP_Query Object
(
[query] => Array
    (
        [name] => signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing
        [post_type] => productmods
    )

[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [name] => signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing
        [post_type] => productmods
        [error] => 
        [m] => 
        [p] => 0
        [post_parent] => 
        [subpost] => 
        [subpost_id] => 
        [attachment] => 
        [attachment_id] => 0
        [static] => 
        [pagename] => 
        [page_id] => 0
        [second] => 
        [minute] => 
        [hour] => 
        [day] => 0
        [monthnum] => 0
        [year] => 0
        [w] => 0
        [category_name] => 
        [tag] => 
        [cat] => 
        [tag_id] => 
        [author] => 
        [author_name] => 
        [feed] => 
        [tb] => 
        [paged] => 0
        [meta_key] => 
        [meta_value] => 
        [preview] => 
        [s] => 
        [sentence] => 
        [title] => 
        [fields] => 
        [menu_order] => 
        [embed] => 
        [category__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [category__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [category__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_name__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [tag_slug__and] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [post_parent__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__in] => Array
            (
            )

        [author__not_in] => Array
            (
            )

        [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
        [suppress_filters] => 
        [cache_results] => 1
        [update_post_term_cache] => 1
        [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
        [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
        [posts_per_page] => 10
        [nopaging] => 
        [comments_per_page] => 50
        [no_found_rows] => 
        [order] => DESC
    )

[tax_query] => 
[meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
    (
        [queries] => Array
            (
            )

        [relation] => 
        [meta_table] => 
        [meta_id_column] => 
        [primary_table] => 
        [primary_id_column] => 
        [table_aliases:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [clauses:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [has_or_relation:protected] => 
    )

[date_query] => 
[request] => SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'productmods'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
[posts] => Array
    (
        [0] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 1294
                [post_author] => 1
                [post_date] => 2018-02-23 17:19:37
                [post_date_gmt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [post_content] => NONE- I selected CLASSIC above|Devils food, fudge and salted caramel|Devils Food, Ganache, Cherry-Vanilla buttercream|Devils food, fudge, graham crumble, marshmallow fluff bc|Almond Cake, Apricot jam, Amaretto buttercream|Coconut cake, passion curd, coconut milk bc|Satisfy the Hunger - devils, snickers caramel, peanut butter bc|Biscoff Cake, Cookie Butter, Cookie Buttercream|Elderflower Soaked Lemon Cake - blackberry jam, vanilla buttercream|Apple Cake, Pear Butter, Caramel Buttercream
                [post_title] => SIGNATURE FLAVORS (select ONE if you chose  "signature" pricing)
                [post_excerpt] => 
                [post_status] => draft
                [comment_status] => closed
                [ping_status] => closed
                [post_password] => 
                [post_name] => signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing
                [to_ping] => 
                [pinged] => 
                [post_modified] => 2018-01-25 16:22:10
                [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-01-25 16:22:10
                [post_content_filtered] => 
                [post_parent] => 0
                [guid] => http://www.leadingdc.com/buttercream/?post_type=productmods&p=1294
                [menu_order] => 0
                [post_type] => productmods
                [post_mime_type] => 
                [comment_count] => 0
                [filter] => raw
            )

    )

[post_count] => 1
[current_post] => -1
[in_the_loop] => 
[post] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 1294
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2018-02-23 17:19:37
        [post_date_gmt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [post_content] => NONE- I selected CLASSIC above|Devils food, fudge and salted caramel|Devils Food, Ganache, Cherry-Vanilla buttercream|Devils food, fudge, graham crumble, marshmallow fluff bc|Almond Cake, Apricot jam, Amaretto buttercream|Coconut cake, passion curd, coconut milk bc|Satisfy the Hunger - devils, snickers caramel, peanut butter bc|Biscoff Cake, Cookie Butter, Cookie Buttercream|Elderflower Soaked Lemon Cake - blackberry jam, vanilla buttercream|Apple Cake, Pear Butter, Caramel Buttercream
        [post_title] => SIGNATURE FLAVORS (select ONE if you chose  "signature" pricing)
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => draft
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => signature-flavors-select-one-if-you-chose-signature-pricing
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2018-01-25 16:22:10
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-01-25 16:22:10
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://www.leadingdc.com/buttercream/?post_type=productmods&p=1294
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => productmods
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )

[comment_count] => 0
[current_comment] => -1
[found_posts] => 1
[max_num_pages] => 0
[max_num_comment_pages] => 0
[is_single] => 1
[is_preview] => 1
[is_page] => 
[is_archive] => 
[is_date] => 
[is_year] => 
[is_month] => 
[is_day] => 
[is_time] => 
[is_author] => 
[is_category] => 
[is_tag] => 
[is_tax] => 
[is_search] => 
[is_feed] => 
[is_comment_feed] => 
[is_trackback] => 
[is_home] => 
[is_404] => 
[is_embed] => 
[is_paged] => 
[is_admin] => 
[is_attachment] => 
[is_singular] => 1
[is_robots] => 
[is_posts_page] => 
[is_post_type_archive] => 
[query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => 1f637d9a855417c5b7cd26de9027165b
[query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
[thumbnails_cached] => 
[stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
[compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => query_vars_hash
        [1] => query_vars_changed
    )

[compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => init_query_flags
        [1] => parse_tax_query
    )

)
```

---

### EDIT 2

As per the comments again, here is the function which calls the `get_mod` function.

```
function add_modifier_fields() {
$fields = array();
$mods = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'square_modifiers', true ); //retrieves a custom field from a product in the db. This has been confirmed to return correctly. 
$mods = explode("|", $mods);

  foreach( $mods as $key => $mod ):
 //this loop also runs as expected, which is why I am retrieving 2 outputs of the $post object.
    $post = get_mod($mod); //$mod is the name (str) of a category which maps to a "productmod". 
    echo "<pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>";
    if($post -> have_posts()):
    //this is where it fails!!! don't know why it is not working. 
    $_mod = $post -> get_posts();
    $match = preg_match('/CLASSIC FLAVORS|SIGNATURE FLAVORS/', $mod, $name);
    echo "<h3>I'm here! </h3>";
...
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full output in both cases? (It would also be easier to read as text instead of a screenshot.)

Comment: There is absolutely ZERO reason that the PHP would operated differently depending on browser, since it is run on the server.  The issue is almost certainly with how you are calling this function - please show how you call this function, including how the parameters / values are being collected (meaning, where does `$post_name` come from?)

Comment: I'll add that as an edit as well. Really, even when you see this, there shouldn't be anything wrong with the call.

Comment: Hopefully you can find an error in what I've just added in the second edit.

Comment: Just wanted to update you guys and let you know that I figured out the cause of the problem, although I still don't know why that is the case.  Apparently in chrome, it doesn't care whether a post is set as a draft or published. I hadn't realized that my productmods were all set as drafts, so when safari queried them, it returned nothing.